# Kubernetes Ingress backend subpath

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Is it possible in any way to redirect a hostpath to a subpath on the backend? Similar how [subPaths](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) work for volumes.

The ingress would look like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jupyter-notebook-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: jptrntbk.MYDOMAIN.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: jupyter-notebook-service
              servicePort: 8888
              subPath: /lab
```

Navigation to `jptrntbk.MYDOMAIN.com` would redirect to `/lab` on the backend and all other parentpaths are unavailable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an Ingress rule with a app-root annotation:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /app1
  name: approot
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: approot.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Check the rewrite is working

```
$ curl -I -k http://approot.bar.com/
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.11.10
Date: Mon, 13 Mar 2017 14:57:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Location: http://approot.bar.com/app1
Connection: keep-alive
```

or can you create an Ingress rule with a rewrite annotation:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

In this ingress definition, any characters captured by `(.*)` will be assigned to the placeholder `$2`, which is then used as a parameter in the `rewrite-target` annotation.

For example, the ingress definition above will result in the following rewrites: `- rewrite.bar.com/something` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/` - `rewrite.bar.com/something/` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/` - `rewrite.bar.com/something/new` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/new`

Source: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Comment: the uproot works excellent: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /lab`

Comment: i'm trying out the rewrite annotation solution for a django rest api, using drf-spectacular for openapi support. It seems like schema from the swagger page is loaded straight from the base path, which results in a 404. 

In other words, the application and it's packages that use internal links, need to be configured according to the rewrite target  (not so easy or ideal), for the solution to work.

Haven't tried the app-root annotation rule yet.