# Kubernetes ingress subpath

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

I want to publish my service in kubernetes. It will redirect the request to / into request to /something. I want to make an ingress so that all the resources of this service are available by some prefix. In other words, I want to see the following example. Any request to ip:80/prefix will be redirected to service:port/ and a redirect from it will be displayed on the client as ip:80/prefix/something. How to do it ?

At the moment I use this solution, but it's not exactly what I wanted. All requests to the ingress root are redirected to the service root.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service1
                port:
                  number: 9999
```

Comment: Take a look to this doc: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/ ; https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/ ; https://stackoverflow.com/a/58453885/21404450